# Qual é o código http adequado para responder o conteúdo de uma imagem?

Tags: php, imagem, header, http-status, http-headers

Bem, a pergunta é bem direta.

Estou querendo usar o PHP para responder o conteúdo de uma imagem. Porém, gostaria de saber se o tipo de status http causará algum impacto quanto ao cliente (como por exemplo, cache de imagens no browser).

No caso, estou utilizando o Laravel 3

```
$cachedImage = 'storage/images/cached.jpg';

$code = ... // Qual deles usar?

return Response::make(File::get($cachedImage), $code, ['content-type' => 'image/jpeg']);
```

Eu deveria utilizar o código `200` ou `304` ? Percebi que no Google Chrome, é retornando `304` para imagens!

Comment: o normal é o código 200 a não ser que vc queira enviar um status específico. Se quer usar uma imagem para representar uma página não encontrada, pode usar 404, por exemplo.

Comment: Mas, no caso, preciso de um status que represente uma imagem existente , porém a mesma deve ser retornada pelo PHP.

Comment: ué.. então é 200 rsrss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso existem as **RFC**, são documentos técnicos desenvolvidos e mantidos pelo IETF (Internet Enginnering Task Force), instituição que especifica os padrões que serão implementados e utilizados em toda a internet.

De acordo com o **RFC 2616**, *seção 10*:

> 10.3.5 304 Not Modified
>
> If the client has performed a conditional GET request and access is allowed, but the document has not been modified, the server SHOULD respond with this status code. The 304 response MUST NOT contain a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.
>
> The response MUST include the following header fields:
>
> - Date, unless its omission is required by section 14.18.1
>     If a clockless origin server obeys these rules, and proxies and clients add their own Date to any response received without one (as already specified by [RFC 2068], section 14.19), caches will operate correctly.
> - ETag and/or Content-Location, if the header would have been sent
>         in a 200 response to the same request
> - Expires, Cache-Control, and/or Vary, if the field-value might
>         differ from that sent in any previous response for the same
>         variant
>
> If the conditional GET used a strong cache validator (see section 13.3.3), the response SHOULD NOT include other entity-headers. Otherwise (i.e., the conditional GET used a weak validator), the response MUST NOT include other entity-headers; this prevents inconsistencies between cached entity-bodies and updated headers.
>
> If a 304 response indicates an entity not currently cached, then the cache MUST disregard the response and repeat the request without the conditional.
>
> If a cache uses a received 304 response to update a cache entry, the cache MUST update the entry to reflect any new field values given in the response.

#### Resumindo

Para sua resposta, você pode usar sim o `304` já que a requisição do usuário não vai modificar nada no servidor e você está apenas retornando a imagem.

Fontes:

- http://canaltech.com.br/o-que-e/internet/O-que-e-um-RFC/#ixzz3eeKVTf3m
- http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 0):

Na realidade, para imagem, nunca vi utilizarem nenhum! O código neste caso é implicitamente 200, portanto, seria redundante inserir 200.

O mais importante é o header que você já está inserindo.

Comment: HTTP response sem código? F12 -> Network...

Comment: Como está utilizando Laravel: **SIM**, sem explicitar response já retorna 200 como padrão.